# i'm having problem making a login system in node js

Tags: node.js

When someone tries to log in and their id and password are wrong, they should be redirected or go back to the login page.

I tried window.location.replace but I don't know why it's not working.

And when someone enters the right id pass they should be sent to the dashboard.

GitHub: https://github.com/GoD-ATHEN/nodedash

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const ifl = path.join(__dirname, '/views/assets/')

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/assets',express.static(ifl));

//CONNECTION CONFIGURATION
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "anoe"
   });

//========== Login =============
app.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login");
});


//==============================
app.get("/loginn", (req, res)=>{

/////////////////////////PROBLEM AREA=========================

    let query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "${req.query.email}" AND pass = "${req.query.pass}"`;
    
    con.query(query, (err, result) => {
      if(err) throw err, window.location.replace("http://phenomit.com");

        if (result[0].email === `${req.query.email}` && result[0].pass === `${req.query.pass}`){
          var status = 1;
        }
        else{
          status = 0;
        }

    });

/////////////////////////PROBLEM AREA END=========================

    res.render("dashboard");

});
//========== Login END ==========


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What is your question? [ask]

Comment: My main problem is that when a user puts the wrong email or pass they should be sent to the login page.

Comment: Put that in your question, not here in the comments section. Still need more detail. What isn't working? What is working?

Answer (score 3):

[`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is not known in your backend. You need to use [`res.redirect([status,] path)`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) to redirect a request.

Also `if(err) throw err, window.location.replace("http://phenomit.com");` doesn't make that much sense. Inside your callback try something like:

```
if (err) return res.redirect(...);
...
return res.render('dashboard');
```

Comment: Thnx for the clarification but it's still not working I already tried res.redirect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
app.get("/loginn", (req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

Why not write as:

```
app.post("/login", (req,res) => {
  ...
})
```

I think it's because you misspell `app.post("login", ...)` to `app.get("login", ...)`, it make `app.get("login", ...)` have 2 function

hope this helps solve the problem

Comment: I will use the post method after completing the login code.
Am using "/login" to load the login HTML page and "/loginn" to run the query and extra things.

Comment: ah sorry i can't see that, have you try " if (err) return res.redirect("/login"); "

Answer (score 0):

You are in the NodeJS context. The `window` object does not refer to your client window. You could handle redirection directly from the client application or just use `res.redirect` from express

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

Making a good and secure authentication layer is not easy and full of pitfalls, including security ones. Get a standard library. You will get lots of complex schemes (like O/Auth, Google, Facebook...) for free. I have used `passport.js` and it is very good. There are others too.